# Check Identity in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

The identity checking in NumPy is different from core Python. I have problem with the result of the method resize.

Compare the method reshape and resize.

1. resize 
   `a = np.array([1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])` 
   `b = np.resize(a, (2, 2))` 
   `a[0] is b[0,0] # return False`
   `id(a[0]) == id(b[0,0]) # return True`
   `a[0] = 1111 # b[0,0] does not change its value`
2. reshape
   `a = np.array([1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])`
   `b = np.reshape(a, (2, 2))`
   `a[0] is b[0,0] # return False`
   `id(a[0]) == id(b[0,0]) # return True`
   `a[0] = 1111 # b[0,0] has its value changed to 1111`

In resize, id(a[0]) equals to id(b[0,0]) means they both point to the same object. It means changing the value of a[0] should change the value of b[0,0] as well. I don't grasp this result why they have the same ID but change a[0] does not change b[0,0]. And did NumPy override the is operator? Two objects having the same ID but the is operator returns False. Can someone answer me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `id` is useless when applied to arrays and their values.

Comment: And don't use `resize`, especially not when you aren't changing the total number of elements. READ the resize docs.

Comment: `reshape` makes a `view`.  `resize` is a new array, copying data from the original. Read up on vjew vs copy.

Comment: I understand the difference between view and copy. And resize will be slower because it make a new array. What I dont understand is the consistence of id. Not like core objects of python such as list. In NumPy, two objects having the same ID don't point to the same object. An Example in list: a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]; b = a.copy(); id(a[0][0]) == id(b[0][0]) returns True. Change the value of a[0][0] makes a change the value of b[0][0] as well. It means when two objects having identical ID, they point to the same object.

Comment: In your list example `a[0][0]` is a reference, a pointer to an integer that exists outside of `a`.  Lists contain references, so `id` is useful in check identify of elements.   An array does not store references (unless it is object dtype).  `a[0]` is a new object with a value copied from `a`; each time you do `a[0]` you get a different object.  The `id` of these objects may be "recycled"

Comment: it sounds strange. If each time I call a[0] there is a new object assigned to a[0] then ndarray will be very slow. Is it correct?

But if I cannot use id to check they refer to the same object? How can I check that? I use the OWNDATA in flags but it isn't helpful. For example a = b = np.array((1, 2)). Both a and b show True in OWNDATA. But change b[0] makes change to a[0]. In this case, id(a[0]) == id(b[0]) returns True.

Comment: `a` and `b` reference the same array

Comment: Yes, I only want to point to that the result from the is operator and id is contradict in NumPy.  In resize, `a[0] is b[0,0]` returns `False` and `id(a[0]) == id(b[0,0])` returns `True`. Change `a[0]` does not change `b[0,0]`. In reshape, `a[0] is b[0,0]` and `id(a[0]) == id(b[0,0])` returns the same results as in resize, but change `a[0]` makes a change of `b[0,0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 arrays:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])
   ...: b = np.resize(a, (2, 2))    
In [3]: a, b
Out[3]: 
(array([1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]),
 array([[1000, 2000],
        [3000, 4000]]))
```

The value of 2 elements:

```
In [4]: a[0], b[0,0]
Out[4]: (1000, 1000)
```

Looking at the `id` of two elements - same???

```
In [5]: id(a[0]), id(b[0,0])
Out[5]: (2642173613776, 2642173613776)
```

But let's first assign those two objects to variables, and then look at ids:

```
In [7]: x=a[0]; y=b[0,0]; id(x), id(y)
Out[7]: (2642173611792, 2642173612208)
```

Those are different, and different from the ids in [5].

Look at this type:

```
In [8]: type(a[0])
Out[8]: numpy.int32
```

This is a NEW object, that contains the value of `a` at [0], but it is not that object (in the list sense).  in [5] Python does `a[0]` and gets its `id`, and then it throws that `np.int32` object away.  It then gets another `np.int32` object to hold `b[0,0]`; and because it didn't hang onto `a[0]`, it reuses the id.  In [7] I take care to prevent that recycling, and we get different ids.  As I tried to tell you from the start, `id` is useless when looking at the elements of arrays.  I repeat **useless**.  The `id` is just the next "handy" value when the object created, and may be recycled.  Values of arrays are "unboxed" values, not references to "items" in the array.

If you want to examine what's 'behind' the array, I suggest:

```
In [9]: a.__array_interface__
Out[9]: 
{'data': (2642096780592, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (4,),
 'version': 3}

In [10]: b.__array_interface__
Out[10]: 
{'data': (2642096780432, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

That `data` number is "roughly" a location for the data buffer that holds the values of the array.  They are different.

For a "row" of `b` the `data` is the same.  It's a `view`:

```
In [13]: b[0].__array_interface__['data']
Out[13]: (2642096780432, False)
```

(but `a[0]` and `b[0,0]` are not views, so their 'data' numbers are different.

`reshape` also makes a view - note the 'data':

```
In [14]: c =np.reshape(a, (2, 2))
In [15]: c.__array_interface__
Out[15]: 
{'data': (2642096780592, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

I won't waste any time looking at `ids` from `c`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Now I understand more about ndarray. I know when you repeat id is useless when looking at the elements of arrays. I should understand that is correct in the context of NumPy (and Pandas...) right? In he core objects of Python, such as list, it is a good indicator for reference. When two element of two list have the same ID, changing one makes a change of the other.

Comment: Yes, the key difference is the for a list `a[0]` references an preexisting object.  For an array, `a[0]` creates a new object (each time it is used).  (Arrays with object dtype do behave more like lists)